# python - selenium firefox portable headless fails

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Trying to get **Firefox Portable v46** to function in **headless** mode. (only portable version that works)

Chrome portable can do this but I would like to know if firefox portable can.

I must include `capabilities_argument["marionette"] = False` otherwise an exception is thrown:

`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`

In normal Firefox (not portable + recent version) ... disabling `marionette` also causes `ops.add_argument("--headless")` to fail ... this is why I believe disabling marionette is the issue.

`os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'` ... Does not work either.

`browser.set_window_position(-3000, 0)` ... works, but only after being visible

I am also running multiple instances of firefox, hiding from task manager might not be an option.

Is there a way I can `import marionette` or get it to work somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that (in windows), once Firefox (most recent gecko-driver compatible version) is installed, the folder in which firefox.exe is kept, is portable.

The folder can be transferred to any windows machine even if it has never had Firefox installed. And the folder containing Firefox.exe will run Firefox successfully

This is the same with Chrome